# Can't get the correct geometry values after MySQL querying

Tags: mysql, python-3

- I have large points data and also a small bounding boxes. I want all the points present within this bounding boxes.

  - With the extent of the `bbox` , I want to get all the points within this `bbox`.
  - With the help of the below code I was able to query and also write it to a `.csv` file.
  - The **geometry** column has non-geometric type variables when comparing the geometry column of the *Queried_values* and *Original_values*.

**Required Output** : get correct geometry values in the SQL queried data

This is my code below :

```py
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="", port=, user="", passwd="", db="db1", charset="")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM db1.table1 where (latitude >=4.139916666666666 and latitude <=52.96272222222222) and (longitude >=5.000083333333333 and longitude <=51.999944444444445)""")
set1 = cur.fetchall()
with open("point.csv", 'w', newline='') as f_handle:
    writer = csv.writer(f_handle)
    header = ['latitude','longitude','geometry']
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in set1:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

My Output:

**Queried_values** : This is the output I get after SQL querying.

> [image: Fig1]

**Original_values** : But I would like get the geometry as in this original file.

> [image: Fig2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of **representing** the geometry.

You can use [`ST_AsText()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_st-astext) to get a textual representation of the the geometry

The query would therefore be similar to

```
SELECT latitude,longitude, St_AsText(geometry)  FROM db1.table1 ...
```